# angular filter duplicating array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i'm having a problem with my angular code.

I'm trying to filter and array using angular filter service but when i get to filtering the array in the filter it duplicates instead of taking each element in the array, i have tried track by but it does not seem to be working.

Here is my angular code:

```
.filter('priceRange', function() {
        return function(arr, range) {
            if (!range) {return arr; }
            var priceResult = [];
            var pRange = range.split('-');
            angular.forEach(arr, function(key, index) {
                if (key.pPice >= pRange[0] && key.Price <= pRange[1]) {
                    priceResult.push(key);
                }
            })
            console.log(arr);
            return priceResult;
        }
    })
```

Here is my html sep up:

```
<div class="col s12 m3" ng-repeat="car in [1,2,3,4,5] | priceRange" >
</div>
```

when i console.log the array in the filter section i get :

```
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    rentTatu.js (line 66)
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    rentTatu.js (line 66)
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    rentTatu.js (line 66)
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    rentTatu.js (line 66)
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    rentTatu.js (line 66)
```

when i try that with a different array i still get duplicates of the array five tims

Comment: Please check this line- key.pPice >= pRange[0] && key.Price <= pRange[1] , it has wrong variable name key.Price, it should be key.pPrice.

Comment: @ Shailendra Singh Deol thanks that is the answer was just a stupid spelling mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter takes a parameter range which is not set when the filter is called. The html should be like,

```
<div class="col s12 m3" ng-repeat="car in [1,2,3,4,5] | priceRange: range" >
```

where ***range*** is the input to the parameter in the filter. The line after the if loop will not be executed unless you pass the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Hello it seems to me that **`range`** value is empty or null, so the whole array is returned , each time it goes to execute the filter , that's why you get the array five times.

What is the value of '`range`' variable?

Comment: hi,thanks for the reply,the range value is a select tag that has a range of prices in each option. But i dont think that is the problem because i console.loged the array and the filter duplicated the array five time instead of filtering it

Comment: Have you tried  console.log('range'); into your filter? After that line : if (!range) {return arr; }

Comment: Yes,it returns the option value selected ,such as 0-4000